# Troubling getting a extjs 6 viewport to scroll internal panel

Tags: extjs

I've got a very simple example that I can't get to show scroll bars. I've tried changing the layout of the viewport to border and the region of the panel to center but no help.

Here is the fiddle and code:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/18no

```
var brs = '<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi<br>hi';


Ext.application({
 name: 'Fiddle',

 launch: function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        layout: 'fit',
        autoScroll: true,
        items: [
            Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',{ 
            html: brs
        })]
    });

 }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all in Extjs 6.0 you'll need to use [`scrollable: true`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-scrollable).

Now, if your using `fit` layout you'll need to put the [`scrollable`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-scrollable) config on the inner item.

([example 1](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/18nq) or [example 2](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/18nr))

Comment: @PeterKellner: autoScroll is *deprected*, see my examples

Comment: Somehow I'm missing something @CD..  I'm not seeing scrollers in your example 1 or  2.  screen shot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8w1vc1kai0n9tye/ext1.png?dl=0

Comment: figured out I needed height: 100%